# Change F77 common bloc to F90 or F95

Tags: fortran, block, fortran-common-block

I have an old fortran program, like this

```
common/blc0/nxt,iwbcoe,iebcoe,iturb,icoord,n,np,npt,igwall,
+        pr,vgp,gwa,rey,cel,eta(81),up(81),deta(81),a(81),yp(81),
+        x(101),xod(101),gw(101),pw(101),ge(101),g(81,2),p(81,2)

common/blc1/ s1(81),s2(81),s3(81),r1(81),r2(81),a1(81,2),a2(81,2)
+            ,etae
common/blc2/expy0a(81),expy0b(81),y0a(81),y0b(81),prt(81),aplus,
1            ro_ks,f,rp(81),dudy(81)
```

I want to convert it to fortran 90 or 95. I don't know whats the meaning of blc0, blc1 and blc2. What is the meaning of 1 and ro_ks at the last line? can anyone change it to fortran 90 or 95, please???

Comment: You're in luck, valid FORTRAN77 code is also valid Fortran95 (with very few exceptions and none of those occur in your code) so the translation of those lines is the identity operation.  As to what the features which are puzzling you mean, well your favourite search engine will turn up far better explanations than I could write; get searching.  It looks to me like you're good to go.

Comment: What you are looking for is a conversion from fixed to free format, if you need hints for searching, and then go on and replace common blocks by module variables.

Answer (score 0):

The `1` marks the line as a continuation line:
http://www.fortran.com/F77_std/rjcnf0001-sh-3.html#sh-3.2.3